# Dynamic dictionary including keywords/ lambda function

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic, lambda, constraints

I have a set of constraints that I have to enter in a specific way in scipy's optimise. The format looks like this

```
cons = ({'type' : 'eq',   'fun': lambda x:    sum(x) - 1.},
        {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x:    bounds(x)},
        {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -1*bounds(x) + 0.1})
```

bounds is a function which calculates a dot product. Without going into too much detail I have to manually create the cons tuple of dictionary during runtime. My question now is, how can I concatenate/ join the keys and values if it includes keywords, e.g "lambda"?

I know how to call a function by a string

```
def install():
    print "In install"

methods = {'install': install}
method_name = 'install' 
if method_name in methods:
     methods[method_name]()
```

But I cannot get my head around how I can get the cons dict working.
thanks

Comment: You have two functions with the same `'type' : 'ineq'`.  Should one of them have a different type?

Comment: What do you need to concatenate/join ?

Comment: one is a lower bound, one an upper , 0 < x < 0.1

Comment: I need to build the whole cons dictionary dynamically and pass it to the optimizer

Comment: `cons` is not a dict, but a tuple of dicts.

Comment: A sorry yes tuple of dicts

Comment: If you have a function named `foo`, then `{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': foo}` is a valid dict. Are you just asking how to store a function in a dict?

Comment: I need to do s.th like '{'type' : 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: sum(x) -1}' + '{'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: bounds(x) }' + .... to create cons

Comment: Combining two dicts is easy, *if* you specify how the values are supposed to be combined. This isn't a syntactic question, but a semantic question. What is the resultant function supposed to look like? `sum(bounds(x)) - 1`? `bounds(sum(x) - 1)`? `bounds(x) and sum(x) - 1`?

Comment: my end result has to look like this cons = {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -1*bounds(x) + 0.1}, {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -1*bounds(x) + 0.2}, {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -1*bounds(x) + 0.3}) I basically have to dynamically insert 0.1,0.2,0.3

Comment: Can you please provide which function in `scipy.optimize` you are trying to call, so we can see the documentation, or at least can explain what the function expects ?

Comment: bounds() is a custom function I wrote which calculates a dot product of an identity matrix and a weights vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a function that returns a function. For example:

```
def constraint_maker(delta):
    def _(x):
        return -1*bounds(x) + delta
    return _

cons = ({'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_maker(0.1)},
        {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_maker(0.2)},
        {'type' : 'ineq', 'fun': constraint_maker(0.3)})
```

The function named `_` (the name is arbitrarily chosen, it could be anything) is a *closure*; the value of `delta` in its body is fixed by the argument you pass to `constraint_maker`.

Note that you can't write something like

```
cons = []
for d in [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]:
    cons += {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: -1*bounds(x) + d}
```

because your `lambda` expression does not create a closure; the name `d` is just a free variable whose value is looked up when it is finally called, and has no relation to the value of `d` when the `lambda` expression is evaluated. The closure is created when you define a function inside another function. You *could* write it as

```
cons = []
for d in [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]:
    cons += {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x, d=d: -1*bounds(x) + d}
```

because now `d` in the body of the `lambda` is not a free variable; it's a local variable (specifically, an argument) whose default value is taken from the variable of the same name in the loop. This is a little uglier, even aside from the confusion of two variables with the same name (but different scopes), because now your function takes 2 arguments, although the second one is never meant to be used explicitly.

Comment: This looks like it will work, the only reason this is necessary is that I will have to input a limit value for every unique entry in my matrix e.g I have a matrix that maps products to countries the constraint will be on any individual country. If I could pass in a vector for + delta this wouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to combine two functions into one, e.g. if you doing something like that:

```
{'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x + 1} + {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x + 2}
```

you want to get:

```
{'type': 'eqineq', 'fun': lambda x: x + 1 + x + 2}
```

If that's the case then try the following:

```
class FunctionSum(object):
    def __init__(self, f1, f2):
        self.f1 = f1
        self.f2 = f2

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.f1(x) + self.f2(x)

class ConstDict(dict):       
    def __add__(self, other):
        _ = {}
        for k, v in self.items():
            if hasattr(v, '__call__'):
                _[k] = FunctionSum(self[k], other[k])
            else:
                _[k] = self[k] + other[k]
        return _

const = [ConstDict({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: x + 1}),
        ConstDict({'type': 'ineq', 'fun': lambda x: x + 2})]

print (const[0] + const[1])['fun'](1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Using your current structure, you could use this code:

```
for c in cons:
    if c['type'] == type:
         fun = c['fun']
         fun(x)
```

where `type` and `x` are your parameters.